# What read throughput should be expected out of google cloud storage from a compute engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get a feel for what I should expect in terms of performance from cloud storage.
I just ran the gsutil perfdiag from a compute engine instance in the same location (US) and the same project as my cloud storage bucket.

For nearline storage, I get a 25 Mibit/s read and 353 Mibit/s write, is that low / high / average, why such discrepancy between read and write ?

```html
==============================================================================
                              DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS                              
==============================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B       5      112.0          52.9         78.2        173.6 
   Delete      1 KiB       5       94.1          17.5         90.8        115.0 
   Delete    100 KiB       5       80.4           2.5         79.9         83.4 
   Delete      1 MiB       5       86.7           3.7         88.2         90.4 
 Download        0 B       5       58.1           3.8         57.8         62.2 
 Download      1 KiB       5     2892.4        1071.5       2589.1       4111.9 
 Download    100 KiB       5     1955.0         711.3       1764.9       2814.3 
 Download      1 MiB       5     2679.4         976.2       2216.2       3869.9 
 Metadata        0 B       5       69.1          57.0         42.8        129.3 
 Metadata      1 KiB       5       37.4           1.5         37.1         39.0 
 Metadata    100 KiB       5       64.2          47.7         40.9        113.0 
 Metadata      1 MiB       5       45.7           9.1         49.4         55.1 
   Upload        0 B       5      138.3          21.0        122.5        164.8 
   Upload      1 KiB       5      170.6          61.5        139.4        242.0 
   Upload    100 KiB       5      387.2         294.5        245.8        706.1 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      257.4          51.3        228.4        319.7 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Write throughput: 353.13 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Read throughput: 25.16 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              System Information                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 
  ##.###.###.##
Temporary Directory: 
  /tmp
Bucket URI: 
  gs://pl_twitter/
gsutil Version: 
  4.12
boto Version: 
  2.30.0
Measurement time: 
 2015-05-11 07:03:26 PM 
Google Server: 
  
Google Server IP Addresses: 
  ##.###.###.###
Google Server Hostnames: 
  
Google DNS thinks your IP is: 
  
CPU Count: 
  4
CPU Load Average: 
  [0.16, 0.05, 0.06]
Total Memory: 
  14.38 GiB
Free Memory: 
  11.34 GiB
TCP segments sent during test:
  5592296
TCP segments received during test:
  2417850
TCP segments retransmit during test:
  3794
Disk Counter Deltas:
   disk    reads   writes   rbytes   wbytes    rtime    wtime
   sda1       31     5775   126976 1091674112      856  1603544
TCP /proc values:
   wmem_default = 212992
   wmem_max = 212992
   rmem_default = 212992
   tcp_timestamps = 1
   tcp_window_scaling = 1
   tcp_sack = 1
   rmem_max = 212992
Boto HTTPS Enabled: 
  True
Requests routed through proxy: 
  False
Latency of the DNS lookup for Google Storage server (ms): 
  2.5
Latencies connecting to Google Storage server IPs (ms):
  ##.###.###.### = 1.1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          In-Process HTTP Statistics                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total HTTP requests made: 94
HTTP 5xx errors: 0
HTTP connections broken: 0
Availability: 100%
```

For standard storage I get:

```html
==============================================================================
                              DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS                              
==============================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B       5      121.9          34.8        105.1        158.9 
   Delete      1 KiB       5      159.3          58.2        126.0        232.3 
   Delete    100 KiB       5      106.8          17.0        103.3        125.7 
   Delete      1 MiB       5      167.0          77.3        145.1        251.0 
 Download        0 B       5       87.2          10.3         81.1        100.0 
 Download      1 KiB       5       95.5          18.0         92.4        115.6 
 Download    100 KiB       5      156.7          20.5        155.8        179.6 
 Download      1 MiB       5      219.6          11.7        213.4        232.6 
 Metadata        0 B       5       59.7           4.5         57.8         64.4 
 Metadata      1 KiB       5       61.0          21.8         49.6         85.4 
 Metadata    100 KiB       5       55.3          10.4         50.7         67.7 
 Metadata      1 MiB       5       75.6          27.8         67.4        109.0 
   Upload        0 B       5      162.7          37.0        139.0        207.7 
   Upload      1 KiB       5      165.2          23.6        152.3        194.1 
   Upload    100 KiB       5      392.1         235.0        268.7        643.0 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      387.0          79.5        340.9        486.1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Write throughput: 515.63 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Read throughput: 123.14 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              System Information                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 
  10.240.133.190
Temporary Directory: 
  /tmp
Bucket URI: 
  gs://test_throughput_standard/
gsutil Version: 
  4.12
boto Version: 
  2.30.0
Measurement time: 
 2015-05-21 11:08:50 AM 
Google Server: 
  
Google Server IP Addresses: 
  ##.###.##.###
Google Server Hostnames: 
  
Google DNS thinks your IP is: 
  
CPU Count: 
  8
CPU Load Average: 
  [0.28, 0.18, 0.08]
Total Memory: 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      387.0          79.5        340.9        486.1 
  49.91 GiB
Free Memory: 
  47.9 GiB
TCP segments sent during test:
  5165461
TCP segments received during test:
  1881727
TCP segments retransmit during test:
  3423
Disk Counter Deltas:
   disk    reads   writes   rbytes   wbytes    rtime    wtime
   dm-0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop1        0        0        0        0        0        0
   sda1        0     4229        0 1080618496        0  1605286
TCP /proc values:
   wmem_default = 212992
   wmem_max = 212992
   rmem_default = 212992
   tcp_timestamps = 1
   tcp_window_scaling = 1
   tcp_sack = 1
   rmem_max = 212992
Boto HTTPS Enabled: 
  True
Requests routed through proxy: 
  False
Latency of the DNS lookup for Google Storage server (ms): 
  1.2
Latencies connecting to Google Storage server IPs (ms):
  ##.###.##.### = 1.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          In-Process HTTP Statistics                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total HTTP requests made: 94
HTTP 5xx errors: 0
HTTP connections broken: 0
Availability: 100%
```

```html
==============================================================================
                              DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS                              
==============================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B       5      145.1          59.4        117.8        215.2 
   Delete      1 KiB       5      178.0          51.4        190.6        224.3 
   Delete    100 KiB       5       98.3           5.0         96.6        104.3 
   Delete      1 MiB       5      117.7          19.2        112.0        140.2 
 Download        0 B       5      109.4          38.9         91.9        156.5 
 Download      1 KiB       5      149.5          41.0        141.9        192.5 
 Download    100 KiB       5      106.9          20.3        108.6        127.8 
 Download      1 MiB       5      121.1          16.0        112.2        140.9 
 Metadata        0 B       5       70.0          10.8         76.8         79.9 
 Metadata      1 KiB       5      113.8          36.6        124.0        148.7 
 Metadata    100 KiB       5       63.1          20.2         55.7         86.5 
 Metadata      1 MiB       5       59.2           4.9         61.3         62.9 
   Upload        0 B       5      127.5          22.6        117.4        153.6 
   Upload      1 KiB       5      215.2          54.8        221.4        270.4 
   Upload    100 KiB       5      229.8          79.2        171.6        329.8 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      489.8         412.3        295.3        915.4 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Write throughput: 503 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Read throughput: 1.05 Gibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              System Information                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 
  ################
Temporary Directory: 
  /tmp
Bucket URI: 
  gs://test_throughput_standard/
gsutil Version: 
  4.12
boto Version: 
  2.30.0
Measurement time: 
 2015-05-21 06:20:49 PM 
Google Server: 
  
Google Server IP Addresses: 
  #############
Google Server Hostnames: 
  
Google DNS thinks your IP is: 
  
CPU Count: 
  8
CPU Load Average: 
  [0.08, 0.03, 0.05]
Total Memory: 
  49.91 GiB
Free Memory: 
  47.95 GiB
TCP segments sent during test:
  4958020
TCP segments received during test:
  2326124
TCP segments retransmit during test:
  2163
Disk Counter Deltas:
   disk    reads   writes   rbytes   wbytes    rtime    wtime
   dm-0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop1        0        0        0        0        0        0
   sda1        0     4202        0 1080475136        0  1610000
TCP /proc values:
   wmem_default = 212992
   wmem_max = 212992
   rmem_default = 212992
   tcp_timestamps = 1
   tcp_window_scaling = 1
   tcp_sack = 1
   rmem_max = 212992
Boto HTTPS Enabled: 
  True
Requests routed through proxy: 
  False
Latency of the DNS lookup for Google Storage server (ms): 
  1.6
Latencies connecting to Google Storage server IPs (ms):
  ############ = 1.3



2nd Run:

==============================================================================
                              DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS                              
==============================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B       5       91.5          14.0         85.1        106.0 
   Delete      1 KiB       5      125.4          76.2         91.7        203.3 
   Delete    100 KiB       5      104.4          15.9         99.0        123.2 
   Delete      1 MiB       5      128.2          36.0        116.4        170.7 
 Download        0 B       5       60.2           8.3         63.0         68.7 
 Download      1 KiB       5       62.6          11.3         61.6         74.8 
 Download    100 KiB       5      103.2          21.3        110.7        123.8 
 Download      1 MiB       5      137.1          18.5        130.3        159.8 
 Metadata        0 B       5       73.4          35.9         62.3        114.2 
 Metadata      1 KiB       5       55.9          18.1         55.3         75.6 
 Metadata    100 KiB       5       45.7          11.0         42.5         59.1 
 Metadata      1 MiB       5       49.9           7.9         49.2         58.8 
   Upload        0 B       5      128.2          24.6        115.5        158.8 
   Upload      1 KiB       5      153.5          44.1        132.4        206.4 
   Upload    100 KiB       5      176.8          26.8        165.1        209.7 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      277.9          80.2        214.7        378.5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Write throughput: 463.76 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Read throughput: 184.96 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              System Information                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 
  #################
Temporary Directory: 
  /tmp
Bucket URI: 
  gs://test_throughput_standard/
gsutil Version: 
  4.12
boto Version: 
  2.30.0
Measurement time: 
 2015-05-21 06:24:31 PM 
Google Server: 
  
Google Server IP Addresses: 
  ####################
Google Server Hostnames: 
  
Google DNS thinks your IP is: 
  
CPU Count: 
  8
CPU Load Average: 
  [0.19, 0.17, 0.11]
Total Memory: 
  49.91 GiB
Free Memory: 
  47.9 GiB
TCP segments sent during test:
  5180256
TCP segments received during test:
  2034323
TCP segments retransmit during test:
  2883
Disk Counter Deltas:
   disk    reads   writes   rbytes   wbytes    rtime    wtime
   dm-0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop1        0        0        0        0        0        0
   sda1        0     4209        0 1080480768        0  1604066
TCP /proc values:
   wmem_default = 212992
   wmem_max = 212992
   rmem_default = 212992
   tcp_timestamps = 1
   tcp_window_scaling = 1
   tcp_sack = 1
   rmem_max = 212992
Boto HTTPS Enabled: 
  True
Requests routed through proxy: 
  False
Latency of the DNS lookup for Google Storage server (ms): 
  3.5
Latencies connecting to Google Storage server IPs (ms):
  ################ = 1.1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          In-Process HTTP Statistics                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total HTTP requests made: 94
HTTP 5xx errors: 0
HTTP connections broken: 0
Availability: 100%



3rd run

==============================================================================
                              DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS                              
==============================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B       5      157.0          78.3        101.5        254.9 
   Delete      1 KiB       5      153.5          49.1        178.3        202.5 
   Delete    100 KiB       5      152.9          47.5        168.0        202.6 
   Delete      1 MiB       5      110.6          20.4        105.7        134.5 
 Download        0 B       5      104.4          50.5         66.8        167.6 
 Download      1 KiB       5       68.1          11.1         68.7         79.2 
 Download    100 KiB       5       85.5           5.8         86.0         90.8 
 Download      1 MiB       5      126.6          40.1        100.5        175.0 
 Metadata        0 B       5       67.9          16.2         61.0         86.6 
 Metadata      1 KiB       5       49.3           8.6         44.9         59.5 
 Metadata    100 KiB       5       66.6          35.4         44.2        107.8 
 Metadata      1 MiB       5       53.9          13.2         52.1         69.4 
   Upload        0 B       5      136.7          37.1        114.4        183.5 
   Upload      1 KiB       5      145.5          58.3        116.8        208.2 
   Upload    100 KiB       5      227.3          37.6        233.3        259.3 
   Upload      1 MiB       5      274.8          45.2        261.8        328.5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Write throughput: 407.03 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied a 1 GiB file 5 times for a total transfer size of 5 GiB.
Read throughput: 629.07 Mibit/s.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              System Information                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 
  ###############
Temporary Directory: 
  /tmp
Bucket URI: 
  gs://test_throughput_standard/
gsutil Version: 
  4.12
boto Version: 
  2.30.0
Measurement time: 
 2015-05-21 06:32:48 PM 
Google Server: 
  
Google Server IP Addresses: 
  ################
Google Server Hostnames: 
  
Google DNS thinks your IP is: 
  
CPU Count: 
  8
CPU Load Average: 
  [0.11, 0.13, 0.13]
Total Memory: 
  49.91 GiB
Free Memory: 
  47.94 GiB
TCP segments sent during test:
  5603925
TCP segments received during test:
  2438425
TCP segments retransmit during test:
  4586
Disk Counter Deltas:
   disk    reads   writes   rbytes   wbytes    rtime    wtime
   dm-0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop0        0        0        0        0        0        0
  loop1        0        0        0        0        0        0
   sda1        0     4185        0 1080353792        0  1603851
TCP /proc values:
   wmem_default = 212992
   wmem_max = 212992
   rmem_default = 212992
   tcp_timestamps = 1
   tcp_window_scaling = 1
   tcp_sack = 1
   rmem_max = 212992
Boto HTTPS Enabled: 
  True
Requests routed through proxy: 
  False
Latency of the DNS lookup for Google Storage server (ms): 
  2.2
Latencies connecting to Google Storage server IPs (ms):
  ############## = 1.6
```

Comment: Throughput is recently rather variable. It's something we're working on, but the mean performance will generally be faster than what you've observed.  Does this happen consistently when you run perfdiag?

Comment: @TravisHobrla these numbers are consistent across multiple perfdiag runs, (I should also specify that this was against nearline storage) but had similar results on a "regular" cloud storage bucket.

Comment: For the nearline bucket, see the note at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/nearline : "Read throughput scales linearly with increased storage consumption", so if you have a low amount stored, this is expected.  For the standard bucket, I think this is on the lower end of variance - if you try a few more runs on Standard do you consistently get ~120Mbps reads?

Comment: @TravisHobrla thank you for the clarification on nearline, this linear scaling of the throughput escaped me.

Comment: @TravisHobrla I did 2 subsequent runs on a standard bucket and achieved 1Gbps (first run) and 186Mbps (2nd run) read throughput using the same perfdiag parameters. The values seem to jump all over the place, I have nothing running on this GCE instance besides perfdiag

Comment: Yes - like I mentioned, throughput is quite variable; definitely an area for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal, write performance is generally higher for modern storage systems because of presence of a caching layer between the application disks, that said, what you are seeing is within the expected range for "nearline" storage.

I have observed far superior throughput results when using "standard" storage buckets. Though latency did not improve much. Consider using a "Standard" bucket if your application requires high throughput. If your application is sensitive to latency, then using local storage as a cache (or scratch space) may be the only option.

Here is a snippet from one my experiments on "Standard" buckets:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Latency                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation       Size  Trials  Mean (ms)  Std Dev (ms)  Median (ms)  90th % (ms)
=========  =========  ======  =========  ============  ===========  ===========
   Delete        0 B      10       91.5          12.4         89.0         98.5 
   Delete      1 KiB      10       96.4           9.1         95.6        105.6 
   Delete    100 KiB      10       92.9          22.8         85.3        102.4 
   Delete      1 MiB      10       86.4           9.1         84.1         93.2 
 Download        0 B      10       54.2           5.1         55.4         58.8 
 Download      1 KiB      10       83.3          18.7         78.4         94.9 
 Download    100 KiB      10       75.2          14.5         68.6         92.6 
 Download      1 MiB      10       95.0          19.7         86.3        126.7 
 Metadata        0 B      10       33.5           7.9         31.1         44.8 
 Metadata      1 KiB      10       36.3           7.2         35.8         46.8 
 Metadata    100 KiB      10       37.7           9.2         36.6         44.1 
 Metadata      1 MiB      10      116.1         231.3         36.6        136.1 
   Upload        0 B      10      151.4          67.5        122.9        195.9 
   Upload      1 KiB      10      134.2          22.4        127.9        149.3 
   Upload    100 KiB      10      168.8          20.5        168.6        188.6 
   Upload      1 MiB      10      213.3          37.6        200.2        262.5 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Write Throughput                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied 5 1 GiB file(s) for a total transfer size of 10 GiB.
Write throughput: 3.46 Gibit/s.
Parallelism strategy: both
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        Write Throughput With File I/O                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied 5 1 GiB file(s) for a total transfer size of 10 GiB.
Write throughput: 3.9 Gibit/s.
Parallelism strategy: both
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Read Throughput                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied 5 1 GiB file(s) for a total transfer size of 10 GiB.
Read throughput: 7.04 Gibit/s.
Parallelism strategy: both
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        Read Throughput With File I/O                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copied 5 1 GiB file(s) for a total transfer size of 10 GiB.
Read throughput: 1.64 Gibit/s.
Parallelism strategy: both
```

Hope that is helpful.